# FeedMe Direct Feed Link not showing in CP

Tags: plugin-feedme, cron

The FeedMe [docs](https://sgroup.com.au/plugins/feedme/feature-tour/trigger-import-via-cron) state that there is a Direct Feed Link for cron usage. I'm not seeing it. All I see is the Debug, Status and Delete icon. Or is this a PRO feature?

I'using Craft 2.6.x and FeedMee 2.0.6

Cheers,
Martijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the confusion, this was updated in the latest Feed Me version, but not reflected in the docs (we're currently re-working them a little).

The direct feed link icon is no more - its not accessible on the first page where you set the name and URL.

Comment: Thanks and I completely overlooked (about a million times) it's on the settings page right in front of me. Keep up the good work.